# What is the probability space in the Infinite Monkey Theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I tried searching everywhere but couldn't find a formalization of this.

I guess the set of possible outcomes $\Omega$ is the set of all sequences of zeros and ones, where $1$ at the $n$th position means that the monkey typed Hamlet correctly at its $n$th attempt, and $0$ otherwise. The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ on $\Omega$ could be the one generated by the sets $A_n$, where $A_n$ is the set of all sequences with $1$ in the $n$th position.

How do we define a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{M})$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = c > 0$, where $c$ is the probability of the monkey typing it correctly in one attempt?

Comment: Are you sure that classically this probability measure is $\sigma$-additive? You might want to look at some fair lotteries over infinite sets and/or to the probability of an infinite sequence of coin tosses. Both have been studied with a classic approach and also with nonstandard analysis. Some references are the papers Elementary numerosities and measures (http://logicandanalysis.org/index.php/jla/article/view/212/93) and Some applications of numerosities in measure theory (http://people.dm.unipi.it/dinasso/papers/Lincei2.pdf).

Comment: This is simply the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega = \{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ with the product topology.  It is the usual setting for considering sequences of Bernoulli random variables.  The probability measure $\mathbb P$ is the product of measures with $\mathbb P(\{1\})=c$, $\mathbb P(\{0\})=1-c$ on each component.